# Zoom with scroll in Chrome browser

Tags: keyboard, macos, google-chrome, zoom

I am new user of OS X, I am missing one important feature is zooming page with trackpad or mouse scroll.

I need to get the same result as shortcuts <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and  <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> do.

I mean that the page should change it size, I need this for responsive web design.

Is there any way to make this work for example using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll</kbd>?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use Command +/- ?

Comment: Yes, I use to use scroll, I need to move my fingers from one part of keyboard to another, I feel really uncomfortable ... I need to change the size of the screen very often, this really a little bit annoying.